# How to cast Array<String> to NSArray full of NSString

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cloudkit

In working with CloudKit, all types need to be Objective-C foundation classes. Since most types used in CloudKit are bridged from Swift to Obj-C   there isn't any issue (i.e. `record[key] = 1 as NSNumber`), but I'm having trouble converting an `Array<String>` to the appropriate CloudKit type (a string list in the CK dashboard). I figured

`record[key] = ([myString] as [NSString]) as NSArray`

would work, but no such luck. How can I convert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bridging will work, together with `NSArray`'s `array` constructor:

```
let a = ["a", "bc", "def"]
let nsa = NSArray(array: a)
nsa[0] is NSString // *** true ***
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

var arrayString:[String] = [str]

var arrayNSString = NSMutableArray()

for p in 0..<arrayString.count
{
   arrayNSString.add(arrayString[p] as NSString)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mapping the array to a new one seems like a lot of overhead for types that are supposed to be bridged.

Comment: Simpler would be `let nsa = NSArray(array: a.map( { $0 as NSString }))`...

Comment: @Grimxn Does the bridging ensure `let nsa1 = NSArray(array: a)` is an array of `NSString`?

Answer (score 0):

the real issue here is that the subscript is broken, you can use `setObject(forKey:)` to use native Swift types!

edit:
I was wrong, `setObject(forKey:)` does not work, however I managed to get passed this issue temporarily by using `setValue(forKey:)` instead. I also extended `CKRecord` with a `subscript` to be used until Apple fixes the issue.

```
extension CKRecord {
    @nonobjc
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        set {
            setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
        get {
            return value(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the subscript, but that CKRecordValue is not adopted by the Swift native types. As with the subscript,  `setObject(forKey:)` also does not work without coercing swift types to obj-c foundation types as of Swift 3.

Comment: you're right. I just looked at my production project, and I can see that I'm using `setValue(forKey:)` instead. I'll update my answer as an alternative.